# Redirect STDOUT to a variable in C without using a file

Tags: c, variables, stdout

I am trying to redirect system stdout to a variable in c, but I don't find a suitable answer, that lets me accomplish this without using a file.

What I need it to do is list all the files in a directory, get the file name, then upload it to dropbox, using another program.

This is what I have so far:

```
char variable[100];

sem_t sem_var, sem_upl;

void *cin(){
    sem_wait(&sem_var);
    gets( variable );
    sem_post(&sem_upl);
    return 0;
}

main(){

sem_init(&sem_var, 0, 0);
sem_init(&sem_upl, 0, 0);

pthread_t thread;
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &cin, NULL);

system("ls /home/pi/foscam"); //list all files
sem_post(&sem_var);

sem_wait(&sem_upl);
char buffer[128];

snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "./dropbox_uploader.sh upload /home/pi/foscam/%s uploads", variable);
system(buffer); //upload file

while(1000000);
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "rm /home/pi/foscam/%s", variable);
system(buffer); //delete file

return 0;
```

}

Unfortunately the "gets" command from "cin" thread won't work for this, so it needs to be replaced with something else...

Comment: Why not use some bash script for this? Design of your program is poor anyway, so bash script would be more suitable in this situation.

Comment: Never heard of it, will look into it :)

Comment: Better yet, use pipes: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html

Comment: Can you please explain why the design is poor, though? Apart from the while cycle, that doesnt guarantee that the file is uploaded before is deleted (which was placed temporarily), I don't see anything bad... If you mean that there are no suitable ways to make this in C, and rather use Bash Script, then yes...

Comment: Use opendir / readdir to loop through the files in a directory.

Comment: in general, never use the gets() function it contains LOTS of problems.  Rather, use fgets().  Amongst other things, fgets() will limit the length of the input so a buffer overflow will not occur.

Comment: is the file './dropbox_uploader.sh' actually in the same directory as where this program is executing?  Is './dropbox_uploader.sh' marked as executable?

Comment: this loop: 'while(1000000);' will NEVER exit.  probably not the action your looking for.

Comment: Gets and while are placeholders, Dropbox_uploader.sh is in the same directory, and marked as executable. No issues with that. I will resume developing, tomorrow, after I check out bash scripting and pipes more in depth. Thanks all